# Android: I don't understand the value from String.valueOf(Time.setToNow )

Tags: java, android

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
return "Time = ["+String.valueOf(now)+"]\n";
```

this is the result

```
Time = [20131020T185424Asia/Bangkok(0,292,25200,0,1382270064)]

2013 = year
10 = month
20 = day
18 = hr
54 = min
24 = sec
```

What does (0,292,25200,0,1382270064) mean?

I also read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#setToNow%28%29)
but still have no idea.

Comment: I would say it's a Timezone, but still not sure about the numbers in brackets. And there is the mysterious `20T` after month as well.

Comment: I think it's Year Month Day, then the T signifies that what comes after is the Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (0,292,25200,0,1382270064)

- 0 is the weekDay
- 292 is yearDay
- 25200 is gmtoff which is the the offset in seconds between the timezone of time and UTC.
- 0 is the isDGT field, which is Daylight Saving Time

You can see the [class source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/text/format/Time.java#Time.toString%28%29) for more help

Answer (score 1):

292 is the day of the year.

25200 represents 7 hours in seconds - I don't know too much about Bangkok time but it might represent the UTC +7.

1382270064 - Number of seconds after MIN_DATE (???) -- Not sure about this one.

The T in the time element:  "Note that the "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601"
http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: What about the rest of the numbers? Other than 292?

Comment: @alex Trying to work them out one by one.  Will update the answer.